# Static variables linker error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, command-line, linker

I'm using Xcode 9.0 for a school assignment, a simple command line program. Getting these odd errors related to static class vars in my one class. I have read several similar questions and have tried changing build setting for architectures from Standard Architecture to Universal. I also tried the other choices, but nothing got rid of the errors. I also tried changing build active architecture only to "no". Didn't help.

Appreciate some help with this. Assignment due tomorrow night. Thanks!

BUILD ERRORS:

```
     Ld /Users/Kelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hw#2_TacoTruck-gzipvvgczeecgketuebotcuumzha/Build/Products/Debug/Hw#2\ TacoTruck normal x86_64
        cd "/Users/Kelly/Desktop/Hw#2 TacoTruck"
        export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -L/Users/Kelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hw#2_TacoTruck-gzipvvgczeecgketuebotcuumzha/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Kelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hw#2_TacoTruck-gzipvvgczeecgketuebotcuumzha/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Kelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hw#2_TacoTruck-gzipvvgczeecgketuebotcuumzha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Hw#2\ TacoTruck.build/Debug/Hw#2\ TacoTruck.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Hw#2\ TacoTruck.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Kelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hw#2_TacoTruck-gzipvvgczeecgketuebotcuumzha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Hw#2\ TacoTruck.build/Debug/Hw#2\ TacoTruck.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Hw#2\ TacoTruck_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Kelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hw#2_TacoTruck-gzipvvgczeecgketuebotcuumzha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Hw#2\ TacoTruck.build/Debug/Hw#2\ TacoTruck.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Hw#2\ TacoTruck_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Kelly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hw#2_TacoTruck-gzipvvgczeecgketuebotcuumzha/Build/Products/Debug/Hw#2\ TacoTruck

    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "TacoTruck::idPool", referenced from:
          TacoTruck::TacoTruck() in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::TacoTruck(int, int, int) in TacoTruck.o
          _main in main.o
      "TacoTruck::coSales", referenced from:
          TacoTruck::TacoTruck(int, int, int) in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::soldCarne() in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::soldPollo() in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::soldVeggie() in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::displayCoSales() in TacoTruck.o
          _main in main.o
      "TacoTruck::coOrders", referenced from:
          TacoTruck::TacoTruck(int, int, int) in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::soldCarne() in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::soldPollo() in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::soldVeggie() in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::getCoOrders() in TacoTruck.o
          TacoTruck::displayCoSales() in TacoTruck.o
          _main in main.o
          ...
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

HPP file:

```
    //
    //  TacoTruck.hpp
    //  Hw#2 TacoTruck
    //

    #ifndef TacoTruck_hpp
    #define TacoTruck_hpp

    #include <stdio.h>

    class TacoTruck
    {
    public:
        TacoTruck();                        //default constructor
        TacoTruck(int carne, int pollo, int veggie);    // Overloaded constructor passing in some sales
        int getID();                       // get Truck ID
        void soldCarne();       //set per number orders
        void soldPollo();        //set per number orders
        void soldVeggie();    //set per number orders
        int getCarne();            // get carne orders accessor function
        int getPollo();            // get pollo orders accessor function
        int getVeggie();            // get veggie orders accessor function
        int getTruckOrders();              // get total orders for this truck
        void displayTruckSales();

        static int getCoOrders();    // get accessor total cumulative orders sold on all trucks
        static void displayCoSales();

        static int idPool;        // Pool to pull ID numbers from
        static int coOrders;        // Total orders collected across all trucks
        static double coSales;      // Total Sales across all trucks

    private:
        int totalCarne;        // Number orders of carne asada tacos sold from this truck
        int totalPollo;        // Number orders of pollo tacos sold from this truck
        int totalVeggie;    // Number orders of veggie tacos sold from this truck
        int id;             // Truck ID


    };

    #endif /* TacoTruck_hpp */
```

CPP FILE:

```
    //
    //  TacoTruck.cpp
    //  Hw#2 TacoTruck
    //

    #include <exception>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "TacoTruck.hpp"

    using namespace std;

    #define CARNE_PRICE 5.49
    #define POLLO_PRICE 4.49
    #define VEGGIE_PRICE 15.59

    TacoTruck::TacoTruck()
    {
        totalCarne = totalPollo = totalVeggie = 0;
        id = idPool++;
    }
    TacoTruck::TacoTruck(int carne, int pollo, int veggie)
    {
        if (carne < 0)
            carne = 0;
        if (pollo < 0)
            pollo = 0;
        if (veggie < 0)
            veggie = 0;

        totalCarne = carne;
        totalPollo = pollo;
        totalVeggie = veggie;

        coOrders += carne + pollo + veggie;
        coSales += carne * CARNE_PRICE + pollo * POLLO_PRICE + veggie * VEGGIE_PRICE;

        id = idPool++;
    }

    int TacoTruck::getID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    void TacoTruck::soldCarne()
    {
        totalCarne++;
        coOrders++;
        coSales += CARNE_PRICE;
    }

    void TacoTruck::soldPollo()
    {
        totalPollo++;
        coOrders++;
        coSales += POLLO_PRICE;
    }

    void TacoTruck::soldVeggie()
    {
        totalVeggie++;
        coOrders++;
        coSales += VEGGIE_PRICE;
    }

    int TacoTruck::getCarne()
    {
        return totalCarne;
    }

    int TacoTruck::getPollo()
    {
        return totalPollo;
    }

    int TacoTruck::getVeggie()
    {
        return totalVeggie;
    }

    int TacoTruck::getTruckOrders()
    {
        return totalCarne + totalPollo + totalVeggie;
    }

    void TacoTruck::displayTruckSales()
    {
        cout << "Total orders for Truck " << id << " is " << getTruckOrders() << endl;
        cout << "Carne tacos sold: " << getCarne() << endl;
        cout << "Pollo tacos sold: " << getPollo() << endl;
        cout << "Veggie tacos sold: " << getVeggie() << endl;
    };

    //static
    int TacoTruck::getCoOrders()
    {
        return coOrders;
    }
    void TacoTruck::displayCoSales()
    {
        cout << "Total company sales: $" << coSales << endl;
        cout << "Total company orders: " << coOrders << endl;
    }
```

MAIN.CPP:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Hw#2 TacoTruck
//

#include <iostream>
#include "TacoTruck.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    TacoTruck::idPool = 0;
    TacoTruck::coOrders = 0;
    TacoTruck::coSales = 0;

    TacoTruck successfulTruck(5, 18, 1);
    successfulTruck.displayTruckSales();
    successfulTruck.soldPollo();
    successfulTruck.soldCarne();
    successfulTruck.soldCarne();
    successfulTruck.soldVeggie();
    successfulTruck.displayTruckSales();
    TacoTruck::displayCoSales();


    TacoTruck badTruck;
    badTruck.displayTruckSales();
    badTruck.soldVeggie();
    badTruck.soldPollo();
    badTruck.displayTruckSales();
    TacoTruck::displayCoSales();

    TacoTruck okTruck;
    okTruck.displayTruckSales();
    okTruck.soldVeggie();
    okTruck.soldVeggie();
    okTruck.soldVeggie();
    okTruck.soldCarne();
    okTruck.soldPollo();
    TacoTruck::displayCoSales();
}
```